# Validación de un textbox

Tags: c#, regex

Necesito validar un `string` obtenido de un `TextBox`, las únicas características que tiene es que debe contener de 1 a 4 letras en mayúsculas y validar con el uso de Regex.

Espero puedan aportar ideas a mi problema.

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^[A-Z]{1,4}+$");
if (reg.IsMatch(textBox3.Text)==true)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Todo en orden");
}
    else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Todo esta mal");
}
```

Lo he intentado así, pero me aarroja este error:

> System.ArgumentException

Comment: Buen día Alan, bienvenido a SOes, edita tu pregunta con el código que has intentado, así nosotros te ayudamos a completarlo :D Por cierto, https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour -> justo y necesario que le des click para que aprendas el correcto funcionamiento del sitio :D

Comment: Tenemos un experto listo. solo hace falta que digas que has probado hasta ahora...

Comment: Lo he intentado así, pero me aarroja este error: "System.ArgumentException"

Comment: ese comentario deberia ir en la pregunta.. porque es un dato importanto. puede que la regex no este mal despues de todo.. te tira ese error al hacer el new?

Comment: Así es, justo cuando entre en el new salta el error

Comment: @alanmorales por esta ocasión he completado tu pregunta con el error que te envía. Para futuras preguntas considera poner toda la información relevante en el cuerpo de la pregunta. Por cierto, bienvenido a [es.so] ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias,es que soy nuevo en la página y apenas me estoy familiarizando

Comment: @alanmorales en ese caso, te recomiendo tomar el [tour] y revisar la sección [ask] :D

Comment: @alan el `+` después de un cuantificador es válido en otros dialectos de regex (Perl, PHP, etc.) y convierten al cuantificador en posesivo. .Net no lo soporta. De todas formas, no es necesario en está expresión.

Comment: En `if (reg.IsMatch(textBox3.Text)==true)` es redundante el `== true`
solo necesitas `if (reg.IsMatch(textBox3.Text))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En la expresión de tu regex sobra el `+`

Con esto debería funcionar:

```
@"^[A-Z]{1,4}$"
```

El más significa de uno a más veces la expresión, pero ya tienes `{1,4}` que significa de 1 a 4 veces así que el + es redundante.

Answer (score 2):

La penúltima expresión `{1,4}+$` no tiene sentido. Le dices que la expresión `{1,4}` tenga una o mas letras pero no se puede aplicar filtro a una expresión y es redundante.

Para que tengas una idea de lo que pasa:

```
  ^ = Buscar desde el principio de la cadena
      [A-Z] = con letras desde la A hasta la Z
        {1,4} = y que tenga de 1 a 4 letras
         + = y que la expresion {1,4} tenga de 1 o mas letras... Espera, una espresion no puede evaluarse.
```

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario usar Regex

```
private void txtOnlyLetter_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    var txt = sender as TextBox;
    e.Handled = !((char.IsUpper(e.KeyChar) && txt.Text.Length < 4) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back);

}
```

Puedes definir el tamaño de ingreso de caracteres con la propiedad MaxLength